# Vue data, computed, and methods

Tags: vue.js

Wondering if I should directly update a potentially large array in `data()` using a method, or instead, have the method set another primitive property in `data()` and use `computed` to return an altered array using that? Examples of both approaches below:

Approach #1:

```
data() {
  return {
    users: [
      {
        name: 'alice'
        selected: true
      },
        name: 'bob'
        selected: false
// ...
methods: {
  handleSelection(selectedIndex) {
    this.users = this.users.map((item, index) => {
      item.selected = selectedIndex === index ? true : false;
      return item;
    });
  }
```

Approach #2:

```
data() {
  return {
    selectedIndex: 0,
    users: [
      {
        name: 'alice'
        selected: true
      },
        name: 'bob'
        selected: false
// ...
computed: {
  usersSelected() {
    return this.users.map((item, index) => {
      item.selected = this.selectedIndex === index ? true : false;
      return item;
    });
  }
//...
methods: {
  handleSelection(selectedIndex) {
    this.selectedIndex = selectedIndex;
  }
```

Is one better than the other or any additional suggestions/improvements? Thanks!

Comment: Based on your code, there can only be 1 selected user at a time but I see `usersSelected()` where "users" is plural and it contradicts with your code. Which one is the correct one?

Comment: A computed property is usually the correct approach here since you don't need to worry about manually recomputing the value.

Comment: @YongQuan - `usersSelected()` was a poor name choice but I can't call it `users()` since that would be a naming conflict with `users` from `data()` in Vue. Maybe should have called it `usersComputed()`.

Comment: So is it true that there can only be 1 user with `selected: true` in whole set?

Comment: @YongQuan - Yes, but that detail is irrelevant to me - just want to know if using computed is better or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a computed property. That way, you don't need to care about remembering to call various methods, to keep data in sync.

Your computed property can be made a bit more simple, with your requirements.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    selectedUserIndex: null,
    users: [{
        name: 'Mark',
        id: 1
      },
      {
        name: 'John',
        id: 2
      },
      {
        name: 'Evan',
        id: 3
      }
    ]
  },
  computed: {
    selectedUser() {
      return this.selectedUserIndex >= 0
        ? this.users[this.selectedUserIndex]
        : null
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <p>
    Selected user:
    <span v-if="selectedUser">{{selectedUser.name}}</span>
    <em v-else>No user selected</em>
  </p>

  <ul>
    <li @click="selectedUserIndex = index" v-for="(user, index) in users" :key="user.id">
      {{user.name}}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Need to pass all the users into a third-party component so I have to define the selected property on all objects in the array, but I'll accept your answer.

Comment: Sounds like it can be avoided. Let me know if I need to update my answer.